# Entity Framework Spacial Data Longitude and Latitude

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, geolocation

I have entered data into a `DbGeography` using the `FromText` option.

For example:

```
DbGeography.FromText("POINT(51.28101 1.076981)")
```

now I have noticed something odd. The 51.28101 is a latitude and the 1.076981 is a longitude so you have `"POINT(latitude longitude)"`. If you paste that into google maps it will take you to a location in Kent, England.

Using the DbGeography field, if I try and pull out the Longitude or Latitude properties, I am given the wrong ones. You can see in this screenshot, the `latitude` property shows 1.076981 and the `longitude` shows 51.28101

[image]

Comment: The FromText function gets wkt(well know text) as a parameter, the wkt for the points is "POINT(X Y)" and so in the case we are using longitude and latitude ...Latitude is the Y and Longitude and the X, so you put the the other way around

Comment: I knew I may have had them backwards but coords are usually written (Long, Lat) and when mapping on bing or google they are expected like that also. Thanks for the clarification. Much appreciated! Add it as an answer so I can accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The FromText function gets WKT(well know text) as a parameter, the WKT for the points is "POINT(X Y)" and so in the case we are using longitude and latitude ...Latitude is the Y and Longitude and the X, so you put the the other way around